# Google Maps setting directions of directionsRenderer object not drawing route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

When attempting to draw a route, the code runs fine but does not render.

Here's a sample code that follows the same structure and behaves the same way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple markers</title>
  <style>    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var routeDisplay = new function() {
      var self = this;
      // Variables
      self.directionsService;
      self.directionsRenderer;
      self.map;
      self.origin;
      self.destination;

      // Functions
      self.setup = function() {
        self.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        self.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          preserveViewport: true,
          suppressMarkers: true
        });
      }

      self.setMap = function(map) {
        self.map = map;
        self.directionsRenderer.map = map;
      }

      self.setPoints = function(origin, destination) {
        self.origin = origin;
        self.destination = destination;
      }

      self.render = function() {
        if (self.directionsRenderer.map == null) self.directionsRenderer.map = self.map;
        self.directionsService.route({
          origin: self.origin,
          destination: self.destination,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            self.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

      self.hide = function() {
        self.directionsRenderer.map = null;
      }

      self.show = function() {
        self.directionsRenderer.map = self.map;
      }

      self.toggleShow = function() {
        self.directionsRenderer.map = (self.directionsRenderer.map == null) ?
          self.map : null;
      }

      self.isAlreadyRendered = function(origin, destination) {
        if (origin == self.origin && destination == self.destination) return true;
        return false;
      }
    }

    function initMap() {
      var myLatLng = {
        lat: 45.5325016,
        lng: -122.7973512
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatLng
      });

      var start = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        label: 'start'
      });

      var end = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: myLatLng.lat - .5,
          lng: myLatLng.lng - .5
        },
        map: map,
        label: 'end'
      });

      // Set up routeDisplay
      routeDisplay.setup();
      routeDisplay.setMap(map);

      start.addListener('click', function() {
        var a = start.position;
        var b = end.position;
        if (routeDisplay.isAlreadyRendered(a, b)) routeDisplay.toggleShow();
        else {
          routeDisplay.setPoints(a, b);
          routeDisplay.render();
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Calling `directionsRenderer.setDirections(response)` should render the route, as the Google Maps API documentation states:

> Call setDirections() on the renderer, passing it the DirectionsResult as noted above. Because the renderer is an MVCObject, it will automatically detect any changes to its properties and update the map when its associated directions have changed.

This exact strategy works fine normally, but in this situation, my `self.render` function is a function inside of an object I use to handle all route rendering.

One should also note that I have confirmed that the map the `directionsRenderer` is using is the correct map and `directionRenderer.directions` does change (as it should).

What could be stopping the route polyline from being rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the `map` attribute of the `DirectionsRenderer`, use the `.setMap` method.  You are currently setting the `map` property of the `DirectionsRenderer`, which is not documented.

```
  var routeDisplay = new function() {
    var self = this;
    // Variables
    self.directionsService;
    self.directionsRenderer;
    self.map;
    self.origin;
    self.destination;

    // Functions
    self.setup = function() {
      self.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      self.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressMarkers: true
      });
    }

    self.setMap = function(map) {
      self.map = map;
      self.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    }

    self.setPoints = function(origin, destination) {
      self.origin = origin;
      self.destination = destination;
    }

    self.render = function() {
      if (self.directionsRenderer.getMap() == null)
        self.directionsRenderer.setMap(self.map);

      self.directionsService.route({
        origin: self.origin,
        destination: self.destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          self.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

    self.hide = function() {
      self.directionsRenderer.setMap(null);
    }

    self.show = function() {
      self.directionsRenderer.setMap(self.map);
    }

    self.toggleShow = function() {
      self.directionsRenderer.map = (self.directionsRenderer.getMap() == null) ?
        self.map : null;
    }

    self.isAlreadyRendered = function(origin, destination) {
      if (origin == self.origin && destination == self.destination) return true;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kevf237y/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var routeDisplay = new function() {
    var self = this;
    // Variables
    self.directionsService;
    self.directionsRenderer;
    self.map;
    self.origin;
    self.destination;

    // Functions
    self.setup = function() {
      self.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      self.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressMarkers: true
      });
    }

    self.setMap = function(map) {
      self.map = map;
      self.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    }

    self.setPoints = function(origin, destination) {
      self.origin = origin;
      self.destination = destination;
    }

    self.render = function() {
      if (self.directionsRenderer.getMap() == null)
        self.directionsRenderer.setMap(self.map);

      self.directionsService.route({
        origin: self.origin,
        destination: self.destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          self.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

    self.hide = function() {
      self.directionsRenderer.setMap(null);
    }

    self.show = function() {
      self.directionsRenderer.setMap(self.map);
    }

    self.toggleShow = function() {
      self.directionsRenderer.map = (self.directionsRenderer.getMap() == null) ?
        self.map : null;
    }

    self.isAlreadyRendered = function(origin, destination) {
      if (origin == self.origin && destination == self.destination) return true;
      return false;
    }
  }

  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {
      lat: 45.5325016,
      lng: -122.7973512
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var start = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      label: 'start'
    });

    var end = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: myLatLng.lat - .5,
        lng: myLatLng.lng - .5
      },
      map: map,
      label: 'end'
    });

    // Set up routeDisplay
    routeDisplay.setup();
    routeDisplay.setMap(map);

    start.addListener('click', function() {
      var a = start.position;
      var b = end.position;
      if (routeDisplay.isAlreadyRendered(a, b)) routeDisplay.toggleShow();
      else {
        routeDisplay.setPoints(a, b);
        routeDisplay.render();
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```